# Compare HTML element with JSON array and replace

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

So I've been trying this for a while but no luck so far. What I want to achieve is, after selecting a value from the drop down, that value should be compared with the json multi-dimensional array. If it matches, then there are certain html elements on the webpage whose content needs to be replaced with the corresponding json values.

Here is the what I've been working so far ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/nj01/fhnzba2q/1/))

```
<select onchange="executeMe(this)" id="selectOpt">
<option value="445">Choose...</option>
<option value="445">Daisy</option>
<option value="446">Romeo</option>
</select>
<br/><br/><br/>
<label id="entity_id">replaceThis</label>
```

So in the fiddle, if the user chooses "Daisy" from the dropdown, (the first array has Daisy in it) the corresponding value set from the array should be displayed in each of the html element on the webpage.

I can use only javascript for this. Thanks in advance guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got problems. First, your string you get back from your map function is massive and certainly won't pass an equality check with your option value. Additionally, your anonymous function is going to return the first value and not iterate through your `for` loop properly. There's no correlation between your select option values/labels and the items in the array. Try this:

```
function executeMe(select) {
    var myselect = document.getElementById("selectOpt");
    var selectOption = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    var i = theArray.length, obj, index, val;
    while (i--) {
        obj = theArray[i];
        for (index in obj) {
            val = obj[index];

            //following matches on both keys and values, if you only
            //want values delete the second part of the check
            if (val == selectOption || index == selectOption) {
                var string = '', prop;
                for (prop in obj) {
                    string += prop + ': ' + obj[prop].toString() + '<br>';
                }
                document.getElementById('entity_id').innerHTML = string;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If this isn't what you need let me know with a comment.

Comment: thanks for your reply Jared. I tried your code, and its returning "[object Object]"

Comment: I've modified the fiddle, please have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nj01/th758xdb/1/)

Comment: Note that the code I wrote will print all the properties of the object. If you only want the matched one replace the `for..in` loop with just `string = val.toString();`.

Comment: Thanks, this is working !! We have some more additional functions in this script, which we are still working on. I hope you'll be available to help...

Comment: All be around, just ask another question. Cheers!

Comment: the keys and the html ids are the same. How do I display the values of the keys to their corresponding html ids on the page ?

Comment: `document.getElementById(prop).innerHTML = obj[prop].toString();`

Comment: tried that, its not working.. when I click JSHint.. I get a red dot at the first line

Comment: am getting this error, "document.getElementById(..) is null". Am getting this at the line document.getElementById(prop).innerHTML = obj[prop].toString();

Comment: `var foo = document.getElementById(prop); if (foo) foo.innerHTML = obj[prop].toString();` You were getting the error because for that particular property there wasn't any HTML element with that id.

Comment: do I give the "if" inside the for loop ?

Comment: The variable assignment needs to happen in the for loop: `for (prop in obj){ var foo = document.getElementById(prop); if (foo) foo.innerHTML = obj[prop].toString();}`